# Get image cropped

Tags: android, image, crop

Im implementing a piece of code that gets the picture from the user cell's library but i want the user to be able to crop the image using the Android default crop UI, so I'm using the code bellow:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 280);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent , RESULT_CODE_PICK_FROM_LIBRARY);
```

and to get the image back I'm using the code on the onActivityResult:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String tempPath = getPath(selectedImage);
Bitmap pickedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath);
```

getPath():

```
private String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }; // MediaColumns.DATA // MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting a null pointer exception on the line:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Does anybody have any clew about this?
Also, what would the code be to take a picture, present the option to crop it and then retrieve the simple image.. there is no need for the original file..

Thanks,
Newton

Answer (score 1):

This [Tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/) is exactly what you need enjoy:

Crop image after Intent pick action
[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this tutorial saves the picture taken to file, and i don't need that, i only need the small size picture that comes… also, it uses undocumented/private code (com.android.camera.action.CROP) that might loose support soon and also doesn't work on every devices/osVersions!

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to crop bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
//    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
//            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth()/2, sbmp.getHeight()/2,
            (sbmp.getWidth()/2), paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


            return output;
}
```

Comment: i have the code to crop a image, but if the image is not square it will loose its aspect ratio.. so i want to implement the Android default crop UI.. any idea how?